# unknown JS obfuscation tool

Tags: javascript

I have seen many obfuscated codes, however, recently I came across this code: [paste2.org](http://paste2.org/p/1380361). The latter uses `arguments.callee.toString().replace(/[\s\'\"\)\}\]\[\;\.\{\(]/g, "").length;` to prevent programmer from simply replacing `eval()` with `document.write` or something similar. I was wondering how do I obfuscate the code this way myself? Is there any tool for that? (p.s. note that `arguments.callee.toString().repl[..]` is called two times) Going deeper. Even when you get trough this stage, the code is complete mess. Variable/function names are randomized, while the strings are complete mess and look something like this: `$(kj49f+4kd+fgdff+hgd25+fh2fg5+adb5)` which evaluates to simply `$('.wrapper .foo[name"bar"]')`. What was used to do that? I have recently came across `jscrambler.com` which is paid JS obfuscation service. I was wondering if it is the thing that was used to obfuscate the code.

Comment: To what end? If your code offers something of significant worth such that someone would want to steal/reverse engineer it to your detriment, then the same would hold even after obfuscation.  As you pointed out yourself, even though the string 'were a complete mess', you were able to determine original values, and others can as well.  Anything proprietary that you want to protect can really only be protected serverside.

Comment: Redundant comment, @Matt. Yes, I do understand that it is impossible to obfuscate code such, that it would be impossible to deobfuscate it. All I want to do is mess up the code as bad as possible – if someone wants it and don't want to pay it, let them work for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few weeks of research, I've discovered that the program used to obfuscate the code in example is http://jscrambler.com/. This is actually a commercial software. Do I recommend it? Hm. Not sure, as I am writing this comment (May 21, 2011), it is still in pretty early stage of development & I've faced multiple issues. Though, they are quite quick to sort them out once reported.